# Subscript in an equation

Tags: subscripts

I would like to add a subscript to my equation. For example the following one:

```
W(P_{r}, P_{q}) = \min_{G} \max_{D \in \mathcal{D}} \mathbb{E}_{x \sim P_{r}}[D(x)]  - \mathbb{E}_{\hat{x} \sim P_{g}}[log(1 - D(\hat{x}))]
```

However, as it is the subscript to \mathbb{E} does not work beneath, but in the right down corner. I would like to achieve sth like:

[image]

How can I do so?

Comment: What exactly is `\mathbb{E}` here? I've never seen this type of syntax before.

Comment: @daleif Peraphs is it an euclidean space?

Comment: @daleif It think it is used to represent the expectation operator.

Comment: @Vincent even if so I've never seen that before and I've edited my share of statistics preprints. That said I think you're right, now what is G then

Comment: @daleif I study probability and I see it all the time. Maybe it is a more popular notation in probability theory than in statistics.

Comment: @Vincent in that case what is G then? D might be some measure.

Comment: Jeez guys, its a formula from Wasserstein GANs, but it's not relevant to my issue. @Sebastiano gave the correct answer.

Comment: \mathbb{E} it is used to represent the expectation operator. Not sure if it is correct though.

Comment: @Vincent It is true. In American books the ℙ is the probability. The E could be a campionary space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look with lot of attention to your formula...Use, for the future, `\underset{}{}` for `\mathbb`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[W(\mathbb{P}_{r}, \mathbb{P}_{q}) = \min_{G} \max_{D \in \mathcal{D}} \, \underset{x \sim \mathbb{P}_{r}}{\mathbb{E}}\log[D(x)]- \underset{\hat{x}\sim \mathbb{P}_{g}}{\mathbb{E}}[\log(1 - D(\hat{x}))]\]
\end{document}
```

[image]